# Text gets truncated when converted from NSString to Swift String

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift

I have this little code to download the HTML source of a webpage.

```
var buffer = NSString(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
// buffer = buffer?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
let html:String = buffer ?? ""
```

While *buffer* does always contain the full sourcecode of the page the variable *html* is always only a truncated piece of it. No matter what webpage I use as path. I used the po (print object) function of the Xcode debugger to check this.

As you can see I already tried to remove whitespaces but it did not help.
Why is the happening and how can I prevent this?

EDIT:

I know I can also use the following method but the the string is truncated too.

```
var buffer = String(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Comment: I do not understand the EDIT: You have repeated the same line from your initial code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `println(html)` in the code. The 'po' command is truncating the string.

Comment: Can confirm. Checked with url `http://httpbin.org/html`. `po buffer` outputs entire string, but `po html` does not. `println(html)` works fine.